# COCO Evaluator results to var

Tags: python-3.x, detectron, coco

I have COCOEvaluator implemented into my Detectron2 network, however I need to output the evaluation metrics (AP) into  variable so I can work with it further. I cant figure out how to do that, or what to call? The only thing that "works" is reading the cell output, but that is clumsy and very time ineffective.

I am calling the evaluator by:

```
 evaluator = COCOEvaluator("test_dataset", output_dir="/content/output")
 val_loader = build_detection_test_loader(cfg, "test_dataset")
 print(inference_on_dataset(predictor.model, val_loader, evaluator))
```

which outputs metrics as:

[Evaluator metrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wv2nn.png)

I need to output the AP values to variables that could be called in future code.
Anyone knows how?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, I don't know why I did not try this earlier:

Just write the inference into a file:

```
                evaluator = COCOEvaluator("manittol_s_test", output_dir="/content/output")
            val_loader = build_detection_test_loader(cfg, "manittol_s_test")

            with open(path,"w") as cpt:
              print(inference_on_dataset(predictor.model, val_loader, evaluator), file=cpt)
```

and read the needed attributes from that file.